# Edge density in Szemerédi's theorem for building graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I asked [a question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653644/confusion-on-applying-szemeredis-lemma-to-graph-building-etc) regarding additional assumptions one needs to make on edge densitites, and the partitions formed in Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma, in order for it to be useful for the counting/building lemma (how many copies of a graph one can find). I was told my question was unclear (I agree it was), so here is a more concrete example to hopefully show my confusion:

Suppose a graph $G$ of order $n$ has $\alpha{n \choose 2}$ edges. In order to 'build' a graph $H$ in $G$, or count how many copies of $H$ we have in $G$, we recall the building lemma:

> Let H be a graph with $\Delta (H) = d$, and which has a r colouring so that no colour is used more than s times. Then if a graph G consists of vertex classes $V1_,...,V_r$ with $|V_i|=n$ such that each pair is $\epsilon$ uniform and has a mutual density $d(V_i,jV)_\geq \lambda$.
>
> Then if $\lambda ^d \geq \epsilon (d+1)$ and $s\leq \lceil \epsilon n \rceil$, then G contains a copy f H.

By extension, if each colour is used once in a graph like a $K_r$, then the aboce lemma guarantees us a $K_r(s)$ with $s$ growing linearly with $n$, and in which there are $s^r$ copies of $K_r$ (thus the counting).

**So to use the counting lemma, we need to find $r$ mutually $\epsilon$ uniform and sufficiently large density $\lambda$ parts. Note that these conditions are coupled: we can deal with a smaller $\lambda$ if we have a smaller $\epsilon$. Vaguely, my confusion is that: smaller $\epsilon$ requires more parts in the Szemerédi partition, but I don't see how the number of parts with large mutual edge density does not grow fast enough with the number of parts.**

Now Szemerédi's lemma tells us that for large graphs, we can find an $\epsilon$ uniform equipartition on bounded number of parts. It does not care about the absolute edge density.

If we construct our $\epsilon$ uniform equipartition on $p$ parts, we have at most $\epsilon p^2$ pairs not epsilon uniform. Thus for any $s$, we can guarantee a $K_s$ of mutually $\epsilon$ uniform pairs, by choosing $\epsilon < \frac{1}{s-1}$. Since we have at least $(1-\frac{1}{s-1} +(\frac{1}{s-1} -\epsilon)){p\choose 2}$ uniform pairs, which guarantees the $K_s$ by Erdős-Stone.

But how about finding enough mutually dense pairs among the mutually $\epsilon$ uniform ones?

My thinking goes like this:

- Szemerédi's lemma tells us nothing about how we distributed the edges. So in the worst case scenario, our $p$ parts have as many as possible edges within the classes. This makes $p {n/p \choose 2}$ concealed edges.
- We started with $\alpha {n\choose 2}$ edges. And so this leaves us with $M = \alpha {n\choose 2} - p {n/p \choose 2}$. Notice that this increases with $p$ with a term $-\frac{n^2}{2p}$.
- So the average density between our parts is $\frac{M}{{p\choose 2} \cdot (\frac{n}{p})^2}$. Which sure enough is still increasing with $p$ but...

Here I am stuck on how to proceed in convincing myself that we can get enough parts so that the fraction of non $\lambda$ density pairs is bounded, say by $\delta$, and that I can make this as small as I like. This is what I would like, so that I can say that the number of $\epsilon$ uniform and $\lambda$ density pairs is at least $(1-\delta - \epsilon){p\choose 2}$. So again I can guarantee my wanted $K_r$ to exploit the building lemma.

I think a relevant point is that these fractions I am obtaining don't seem to depend on $n$. So I can always assume that my $n$ is large enough for 'averaging' to work? Not sure about this.

Hopefullty this is clearer than my previous post.